# How to check/list all files changed in PR with multiple commits

Tags: git, pull-request, jenkins-groovy

I want to check the files changed in a PR which might have multiple commits.I have seen multiple answers on how to see the files changed between two commits but that is not my use case. 
I have a folder called "test-proxy" in my repo. I'm triggering test-proxy deploy stage in the pipeline only if there is a change to the test-proxy folder. 
Say, I open a PR

commit 1 - no changes in test-proxy folder -> test-proxy deploy stage does not trigger (expected)

commit 2 - changes in test-proxy folder -> test-proxy deploy stage triggers (expected)

commit 3 - no changes in test-proxy folder -> test-proxy deploy stage does not trigger - (not expected)!

This is not ideal because test-proxy test cases might have failed in commit 2 which will get overlooked if the stage does not run again. We cannot leave it on the discretion of the developer to ensure that the stage passes. It should be handled by the pipeline.
Now in order to run the test-proxy deploy stage for this PR, the developer will have to make dummy commit to the folder.

Please help in resolving the above concern.

I have tried most of the git commands I found in other answers for testing. These two are the ones I had in my pipeline even though they don't give the exact result -

1. git diff-tree --name-only HEAD^ HEAD | grep test-proxy
2. git show --no-commit-id --name-only -r $(git log --pretty=format:'%h' -n 1) | grep test-proxy

Expected -

test-proxy deploy stage should always trigger when any commit in the PR has a change to the test-proxy folder.

Comment: Hey, just for clarification You want to deploy the specific commit when the change occurred? Because that is what I understand from Your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to detect any difference between the tip of the PR and the point where the PR branched off of your current branch (call it `master`):

```
git diff-tree --name-only $(git merge-base master HEAD) HEAD -- test-proxy
```

If you are just interested in *whether* there was a change, throw in `--quiet` and `--exit-code`:

```
git diff-tree --quiet --exit-code $(git merge-base master HEAD) HEAD -- test-proxy
```

Note that this will report success if there are *no* changes in `test-proxy`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Since I'm using the above command though Jenkins, I had to make a minor change
(git merge-base refs/remotes/origin/master HEAD)